# Moved QT project, Rename folders and project name, Moc'ing return "Missing value after '-I'"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, build, qt5

I have a working Qt 5.11 Project in Visual Studio 2017.

When I moved a Project to Another folder, renamed Project name and changed some include folder names and tried to build the Project I get...

```
1>Moc'ing includes\ThreadChecker.h...
1>Missing value after '-I'.
```

… On all my Moc-able classes and no moc-files is generated at all, but the Generated Files-folder is created, and the moc-files in visual studio is shown, but the physical files is not generated, so I can not build the Project because there is no files.

I tried to google the Missing value after '-I' but I can not see someone got that error.

Somebody got know anything about that error?

Comment: Since `-I` is used for includes, most likely you have an empty include somewhere. I'd suggest turning on the compiler verbosity (as explained here - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/10/07/did-you-know-you-can-configure-the-msbuild-verbosity-in-the-output-window-329/) or in some other way examine the actual command line being invoked. Then when you verify that there actually is an empty include setting you can start going through the project configuraiton to find out where there is a bland include value.

Comment: I had this. It was because of a "-I$(NOINHERIT)" at the end of the custom build command.

Comment: Hi Paul, I had the same issue. Thanks to your answer, I opened the project file and manually removed "-I$(NOINHERIT)". Everything worked fine now.

Answer (score 2):

When I have this issue, I edit project file (*.VCPROJ) replacing "-I$(NOINHERIT)" by "-I$(NOINHERIT)\.".

```
<CustomBuild Include="\source.h">
  <AdditionalInputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(QTDIR)\bin\moc.exe;%(FullPath)</AdditionalInputs>
  <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Moc%27ing %(Identity)...</Message>
  <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">.\GeneratedFiles\$(ConfigurationName)\moc_%(Filename).cpp</Outputs>
  <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">[...]"-I$(NOINHERIT)\."</Command>
```

I can't explain yet exactly why and when this file is broken but when you look at working Moc'ing, it is with the trailing "\." character.